# PDF form using Cognos

Tags: pdf, textfield, cognos, pdf-form

We want to create a Cognos report which renders a PDF output with an editable text field. Some of the values in the report will be retrieved from Database and one editable text field should be available which a user can manually edit outside of the report studio using pdf editors.

How do we create this editable text field in cognos?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any method I'm aware of to do this shy of using some post-processing code external to Cognos to edit the PDF and insert what you're looking for in a particular location.

You would need to ask IBM to add an enhancement to Cognos to get this to happen.